# Swift - Init method and randomizing not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

When I run this code, I receive no errors, but the only problem is that I've tried an "init" method to randomize the objects textures. I used an init method because before I was having a problem with the instance variable randomizer variable to not be used on type 'Gamescene'. However now, the randomizer does not randomize anymore.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


struct randomize {

    var randomizer: Int

    init() {

        randomizer = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))

    }
}

var r = randomize()

var object = SKSpriteNode()

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {


    if object.position.y < 25 {


        object.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "object\(r.randomizer)")

    }
```

Comment: That is a lot of work, just do `func randomizer() -> Int { return Int(arc4random_uniform(3))}`

Comment: also, you do not want to do this,  you will generate a texture every frame if position is < 25.  this is bad

Answer (score 1):

"randomizer" variable is generated when you init this struct, but it is not randomized again when you try to access it. In order to have a different value each time you access it, you need to create a getter for "randomizer" and generate a value there.

```
struct randomize {
    var randomizer: Int {
       return Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
    }

    init() {
    }
}
```

Comment: If I replace the struct with the code above, then I get an error saying "Instance member 'randomizer' cannot be used on type 'Gamescene'. I get this error on the var object = spriteNode(imageNamed: "object\(randomizer)" @Eluss

Comment: You can add "randomizer" var to your struct. Can you please paste exact code  where you use simple var without getter?

Comment: @Jeffrey you need to do `"object\(r.randomizer)"`, you missed the `r.`

Answer (score 0):

**As @knight0fdragon commented, you really shouldn't be using the struct and should be using a function.**

Your struct:

```
struct randomize {
    var randomizer: Int
    init() {
        randomizer = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
    }
}
```

Should just be the function:

```
func randomizer() -> Int{
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
}
```

Where you'll just have to call:

```
randomizer() // new value
```

**If you want to use the struct it should be:**

```
struct randomize {
    var randomizer: Int!
    init() {
        randomizeR()
    }
    mutating func randomizeR(){
        randomizer = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
    }
}
```

Where you use it like this:

```
var r = randomize()
print(r.randomizer) // initial value
print(r.randomizer) // initial value
r.randomizeR()
print(r.randomizer) // new value
```

**Or even more simply:**

```
struct randomize {
    var randomizer: Int {
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
    }
}
```

Where you use it like this:

```
var r = randomize()
print(r.randomizer) // initial value
print(r.randomizer) // new value
print(r.randomizer) // new value
```

Comment: @Jeffrey, if this worked for you, select the check mark next to my answer.